# Alfresco is not moving old file to contentstore.deleted when updating file with FTP

Tags: alfresco

When I update/overwrite a file with same file using FTP in alfresco, alfresco is creating multiple copies of this file in its `contentstore`. Alfresco is not moving old copies of this file in `contentstore.deleted` folder. This will unnecessarily increase `contentstore` size.

I want alfresco to move old file to `contentstore.deleted` when I update/overwrite same file in alfresco using FTP.

If I update this file with new file having different file size then alfresco is moving old file to `contentstore.deleted`, problem is only for updating with same file.

Also tried this by setting `system.content.eagerOrphanCleanup=true`, `system.content.orphanProtectDays=0` and `system.content.orphanCleanup.cronExpression=0 0/1 * * * ?` in repository.properties but alfresco is not moving old files to `contentstore.deleted`

Comment: What version of Alfresco is this with?

Comment: I have tried this on Alfresco 3.4d and Alfresco 4.0a

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug, but it's likely worth re-testing with 4.0b before [reporting it](http://issues.alfresco.com/)

Comment: after doing many test found bug in alfresco FTP. If we replace one file with same file using FTP, alfresco do not make old content orphan. This is increasing 'alf_data' folder size. If we do this using JCR it works fine, so the problem is with FTP protocol in alfresco.                             Thanks for helping me in this problem, now adding this bug in the http://issues.alfresco.com/

Answer (score 3):

In Alfresco document deletion is a multistep process. In the first step nodes are "*archived*" and still remain in the contentstore, i.e. you should find them in the **alfresco trashcan** when you login into Alfresco Explorer as an admin (-> from the admin user profile). Only when they are removed from the trashcan they will be moved to the contentstore.deleted folder.

Have a look at this blog to understand the process. They even have a module to automate the deletion from the trashcan:
http://alfrescoshare.wordpress.com/2009/12/17/understanding-alfresco-document-life-cycle-for-backup-strategy/

Note that by setting the option `system.content.eagerOrphanCleanup=true`
your content files will be deleted immediately when you delete them from the trashcan and will not be moved to `contentstore.deleted` at all.